# Was there any kind of preventative collision training for dogfights during WWI and WWII?

Tags: flight-training, wwii, dogfighting, mid-air-collision

Watching some old films on YouTube about dogfighting has me curious about this. Definitely seems like most dogfights around this time were extremely close, involving tight formations and turns. Was there any kind of preventative collision training that the pilots went through around this time? Or was the goal just to get them through training ASAP?

Comment: I would think that the self-preservation instinct would be a pretty strong "anti-collision" measure.

Comment: In WWII, some pilots were sent into action with as little as 20 hours of training, so I'm guessing that collision avoidance wasn't a big topic.

Comment: Tight formations were going into the fight and returning to base. In the dogfight itself it was just wingmen trying to cover their leaders from further behind. In the dogfight itself the aircraft are also only just a small part of all the dangerous objects you are trying to avoid.

Comment: I would guess "none" is a good answer.

Comment: @ManuH I asked this question on another site, and it finally got an answer as well. What do you guys think of this? https://www.quora.com/Was-there-any-kind-of-preventative-collision-training-for-dogfights-that-pilots-learned-before-going-to-war-in-either-WW1-WW2/answer/Jay-Thompson-120?ch=10&share=04950016&srid=erNIm

Answer (score 2):

No, there was no anti-collision training aside from "dodging the fireball" after enemy aircraft shootdown. The training resources and timeline didn't permit much training beyond safe employment of the aircraft gun.